# How to make a copy of an object in ebean

Tags: model, playframework, playframework-2.0, persistence, ebean

I am working with play[0] application and I am using ebean[1] as my object-relational mapper.
We have some models which are "immutable" and we need to clone/copy those every time something is changing.

The actual question is:
What is the proper way to create a copy of an object that has been retrieved from the orm? And how to handle relations with referencing

We have tried to nullify ids and persist models again, but in this case ebean still keep the relation with previous models.

```
User user = Ebean.find(User.class, id);
user.setId(null);
user.save(); //will not create a copy
```

Also I tried to use Ebean._ebean_createCopy()[2] but this doesn't make a deep copy, I think.

```
User user = Ebean.find(User.class, id);
User another = user._ebean_createCopy();
another.setId(null);
another.save(); //will create a new user but keeps the old references
```

- [0] http://www.playframework.com/
- [1] http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introduction.html
- [2] http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/bean/EntityBean.html#_ebean_createCopy()

Comment: How Ebean is supposed to know which relations you want to keep or not? _ebean_createCopy() creates a copy of the object. After that you can set the fields that are part of a relation to null or anything you want by yourself and keep the properties you want.

And you can always use raw sql in Ebean if everything else fails.